# How to format date in correct format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I'm working on JavaScript and stuck in a small issue.

I am receiving this date in JSON response `1322919399447-0500`

and I want to format this like:  `6:50 PM, Dec 3rd 2011`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Comment: Is a popular topic, you can find on the existing questions (surely it does)

Comment: Can you please revisit this question, check the answers and accept the one you like the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way (I'm sure it's not, actually), but essentially you can make that datestring into a js Date object, then pull out the pieces to manipulate as you see fit:

```
var dateThing = new Date(1322919399447-0500);
dateThing.getFullYear(); // 2011
dateThing.getDay(); // 6
dateThing.getDate(); // 3
dateThing.getMonth(); // 11
dateThing.getHours(); // 8 (test for anything over 12, that indicates PM)
dateThing.getMinutes(); // 36
```

Then you can concatenate those pieces into your own format. Like I said, there's probably a better way, but this works in a pinch.

Comment: Oh, and tons of good stuff in that post ajreal mentioned. Check it out.

Comment: The `-0500` in the Date constructor isn't a good idea. For one, it's intended to be a timezone offset (number of hours from UTC). For another, `0500` outside strict mode will result in `320`, the decimal value for octal `0500`.  So actually, you're taking 320 milliseconds away from the actual date value, instead of 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I used this handy little [date format addon](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) and it worked very well for me.  Even took care of the pesky internet explorer quirks with the month.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/TDNwV/) is the snippet with your example input. It is using [script](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) linked by *Zoidberg*.

This code returns formatted UTC date. If you want your local date then remove `UTC:` from the `return` statement.

```
function convertTime(dateString) {
  // get ms part from the string
  var milis = +dateString.substring(0, 13);
  // get timezone part as "# of hours from UTC", e.g. "-0500" -> -5
  var offset = +dateString.substring(13, 16);
  // move the time for "offset" number of hours (to UTC time)
  var date = new Date(milis - offset * 3600000);
  // using http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js
  return date.format("UTC:h:MM TT, mmm dS yyyy");
}
```

*EDIT*: Changed `+ offset *` to `- offset *` as we want to normalize to UTC.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar date format function I created that uses the same flags that PHP's date function uses.

[PHP date function in Javascript](http://www.andbeyonddesign.com/Blog/2011/10/Javascript-function-to-mimic-PHP-date-function)